# How to get values of multiselect box in PHP

Tags: php

My multiselect box is created like this:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',"1");

    $select = '<select multiple>';

    $lines = file('project-list.txt');
    $fifth_column = array();
    foreach ($lines as $line){
        $parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $line);
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($parts as $partVal){
            if ((in_array($partVal, $fifth_column) == FALSE) && $count == 4){
                $fifth_column[] = $partVal;
            }
            $count++;
        }
    }

    foreach($fifth_column as $value){


        $select .= "<option value='".$value."'>".$value."</option>";
    }

    $select .= '</select>';

    echo $select;





?>
<form action="" form method="post">
<input type="submit" class="ym-button ym-small" name = "Apply" style="margin-top:1em;max-width:11em" value="Apply" />
</form>
```

I want to be able to see what the user has selected in the box when the apply button is clicked, I want to use this information to search the project-list.txt for the value they have selected, and then display the lines that contain that value. I have been trying to use isset($_GET) however my select box doesn't have a name.

ADDED:

For example:

If my list box contains:
item1
item2
item3
item4

and the user selects item1, I want to search in a text file called project-list.txt for item1 and print that line. So my text file may look like:

```
xxxx  hallone item 1
xxxx  halltwo item 2
xxxx  hallthree item 3
xxxx  hallfour item 1
```

After I have clicked the Apply button, after choosing item1 the results should be posted which would be:

```
xxxx  hallone item 1
xxxx  hallfour item 1
```

Comment: Give the `select`tag a `name="something"` attribute and place it inside the `form` element.

Comment: You get values by their name and by sending them with a form and a submit button. So **give a name to your select and put it in your form**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Code

```
    <form action="" method="post"> 
    <?php
        ini_set('display_errors',"1");

        $select = '<select multiple name = "project[]">'; // give name attribute to your select box

        $lines = file('project-list.txt');
        $fifth_column = array();
        foreach ($lines as $line){
            $parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $line);
            $count = 0;
            foreach ($parts as $partVal){
                if ((in_array($partVal, $fifth_column) == FALSE) && $count == 4){
                    $fifth_column[] = $partVal;
                }
                $count++;
            }
        }

        foreach($fifth_column as $value){


            $select .= "<option value='".$value."'>".$value."</option>";
        }

        $select .= '</select>';

        echo $select;





    ?>
    <input type="submit" class="ym-button ym-small" name = "Apply" style="margin-top:1em;max-width:11em" value="Apply" />
    </form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['project'])){
    print_r($_POST['project']);
}
?>
```

Comment: is there a way I can put the value of 'project' into a variable? So I can use this to search the textfile? Thank you @Dhinju Divakaran

Comment: Yes you can put `$project = $_POST['project']` notice that it is a array. If this answer is useful then accept this answer